# Not able to clone github directory through proxy server

Tags: proxy, github

I am not able to clone a particular github branch ! It shows following error when I try to do so as I have a squid proxy server in my university.

```
       Cloning into 'ws'...
       error: The requested URL returned error: 407 while accessing https://github.com/abcd/efg.git/info/refs
       fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Please Help !!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add the proxy server into your `.gitconfig` (it is located in your `$HOME` folder)

```
 [http]
        proxy = http://username:passwd@your-proxy-ip:your-proxy-port
```

example:

```
 [http]
        proxy = http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:3128
```

this must be placed in the `[core]` section of your gitconfig. 
See [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) for more documentation